# File name issue in cron-job

Tags: linux, apache, cron, mysql

Below command is working fine:

```
mysqldump -u root -proot db_name > /home/ronak/$( date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S" ).sql
```

But, when I put exact same command in `crontab` I am not getting any output. I tried with changing the file name with `test.sql`, in that case I am getting that file on desired location. I think something is wrong in `date` in `crontab`.

```
* * * * * root mysqldump -u root -proot db_name > /home/ronak/$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H_\%M_\%S" ).sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Some distros don't like the $() construct in cron. To test in cron try touching a file in, say, /tmp:

```
* * * touch "/tmp/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt"
* * * touch "/tmp/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).csv"
```

See if either file appears in /tmp

(a) one appeared in file system after `touch`:

Perhaps an outer wrapper double quote needed around the filename after `>` symbol in your problem cron command.

(b) neither appeared:

Create a bash script and fire that off inside cron task as it has more power with dates:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=`/bin/date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
  NOW="date_not_great"
fi

mysqldump -u root -proot db_name > /home/ronak/$NOW.sql
if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
  echo "$0: backup failed with error code $?"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for good troubleshooting advice.  Cron suffers from an embarrassing design decision related to `%` signs having a magical meaning. Escaping them (iirc) with backslash doesn't quite work because cron passes the backslash intact, to what it assumes is the shell, but this often does the wrong thing.  The bash script workaround is the easiest solution (though you might want to capture `$?` in a variable and then reuse that value to `exit` at the end of the script so the script exits abnormally if an error occurs).